# VB.NET properites not seen in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a project in vb.net that I use for authentication.  I referenced it within my C# app and all works till I get to basically getting the user.  Here is a property

```
Public ReadOnly Property UserId() As String
    Get
        Return _userId
    End Get
End Property
```

Is there a way for me to rewrite in C# or could it be something else that C# does not like?
and here is the code that references the Class. _theUser comes back null.  which leads me to suspect the properties in vb are not being read.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private ADSecurity.UserCredentials _theUser;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

         _theUser = (ADSecurity.UserCredentials)Session["thisUser"];
        if (_theUser.IsValidUser)  
            {
                if (_theUser.IsAdminGroup | _theUser.IsManagersGroup |
                    _theUser.IsProjManagersGroup | _theUser.IsProduction |
                    _theUser.IsSales | _theUser.IsFlight | _theUser.IsSupport)
                {


                }
```

Comment: Have you used ildasm to see if its in the assembly

Comment: I don't see any mention of the UserId property in the C# code, did you paste the wrong code?

Comment: _theUser is a UserCredentials object. What does this have to do with the string property UserID?

Comment: idd, no mention of that property in the c#, did you want some1 to write that prop in c#?

Answer (score 1):

if _theUser is null then you have probably never put anything in Session["thisUser"].

I don't see any relation to the UserId property.